# relatively new monitor cannot display 1024x768

Tags: display, vga

I have a Philips monitor capable of displaying 1680x1050, which I am currently using and it works fine.  But sometimes I'd like to connect this monitor to an older laptop whose native resolution is 1024x768.  But when I connect the laptop's external video output to the monitor, I can see only about 80% of the display (ie, the boundaries are not correct).  I tried to adjust the monitor's settings (via the monitor's own buttons) but it doesn't work.  Nor the "auto adjust" button on the monitor.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not really a good fit for this site, sorry. I proposed migration to one of the daughter sites, but not sure if it will be accepted.

Comment: Point is consumer electronics are off topic here per our [faq]. I voted for migration as well.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not helpful. What goes wrong?

Comment: The boundaries are not right -- the monitor is displaying only the middle "window" of what should be displayed -- the outermost areas disappeared into the margins -- on all sides.  I can adjust that "window" to move around a bit (using monitor's buttons), but never able to view the entire screen.  I expect the monitor should work because it is capable of much higher resolution, and 1024x768 is very standard....

Comment: For example, I press "auto adjust" on the monitor, and the display wriggles a little (not much), and still the result is that only the central portion is displayed.  I also tried to adjust the horizontal and vertical positions, the "frequency" (tried all its range), and the "phase", all have little to no effect.